# Firefox scroll issue on jQuery One Page Scroll

Tags: jquery, firefox, scroll

I found a plugin which allows a single page to show content at full width/height, but it does not work properly on Firefox 27.0.1.

Am I missing something? Are you facing the same problem?

[ONLINE DEMO](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looking forward on Github issues, I found a post by "gianu" user which find the problem on binding events.

The following sentence is a copy / paste from his own:

> On Firefox 27 on OSX, if you're using a mouse the scroll event is not always fired. **The solution that I found is to add MozMousePixelScroll to the bind list.**